# Pandas subtracting same number from each row of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframes as:

```
df1['A'].ix[1:3]
2017-01-01 02:00:00    [33, 34, 39]
2017-01-01 03:00:00    [3, 43, 9]

df2['B'].ix[1:3]
2017-01-01 02:00:00    2
2017-01-01 03:00:00    3
```

I want to perform the following:

```
difference = df1 - df2
```

Expected result is:

```
(df1 - df2).ix[1:3]
2017-01-01 02:00:00    [31, 32, 37]
2017-01-01 03:00:00    [0, 40, 6]
```

i.e. substract number in `df2` from corresponding list in `df1`

Each list of `df1` have same size.

I can't think of better way than `list comprehension`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert your column values from a list to a numpy array and then do `df1.A - df2.B`:

```
df1.A = df1.A.map(np.array)
difference = df1.A - df2.B
```

Comment: Simple, but very elegant solution !

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell what the objects are in `df1`.  Might be `list` maybe `np.array`?  IDK?

Better I create my own example

```
A = pd.Series([[33, 34, 39], [3, 43, 9]])
B = pd.Series([2, 3])
```

***option 1***
`apply(np.asarray)`

```
A.apply(np.asarray) - B

0    [31, 32, 37]
1      [0, 40, 6]
dtype: object
```

***option 2***
*uglier but faster, see below*

```
pd.Series((np.array(A.values.tolist()) - B.values[:, None]).tolist(), A.index)

0    [31, 32, 37]
1      [0, 40, 6]
dtype: object
```

***timing***

[image]

Comment: I like this one too !

Comment: Can you explain the `A.apply(np.asarray) - B` part to a Pandas newbie? Is that simply converting it into an array (I assume `np.` is numpy?) ? And if so, why would one choose the numpy array over other options? Thanks!

Comment: @patrick `apply` takes a function as an argument and applies it to each element of the series `A`.  It produces another series in with all the same row indices but instead of the old values of `A` you get `np.asarray(x)`  instead, where `x` is any one particular value in `A`.  We almost always `import numpy as np`.  Grr's `np.array` works very similarly.